# Infinite scrolling of shuffled database values

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I currently have an infinite scroll that prints blocks of database rows as the user reaches the bottom of a page.

What I'd like to do is shuffle the entire database so that the user gets them all in a different order each time the page is loaded (but no entries appear twice).

This table is only going to grow so I'd like to do it as efficiently as possible.

My query is currently:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM shopaholic ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 36");
```

This has two distinct disadvantages:

- It's liable to repeat rows because it's picking rows from the entire table every time
- It's using `RAND()` so it's going to be really slow

How would I go about this in a better way?

Let me know if there's other relevant code that you need to see.

Comment: You’re sorting randomly. You’re either going to have to create a pseudo-random order, or store what records have been viewed on the client side, where you may run into problems with the client slowing down or hitting local storage size limits if you have lots and lots of records.

Comment: I'm fine with pseudo-random - how might I go about that?

Comment: This is a combinatoric P=NP problem and can be computationally expensive - your best bet is to pre-generate a set of shuffled displays and make it appear random to end-users. Otherwise, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

Comment: Pseudo-random means you would actually generate an order before hand, and then page from that list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to keep track of which records the user has seen already, then they're still likely to see the same record if they refresh the page.

You might consider giving up the requirement that they don't see any repeats, since it is the most demanding requirement. Maybe just add some logic so that they don't see duplicates on the same page, so at least it won't be so obvious.

Ordering by `RAND()` will scan all rows in the table. Assuming you have some auto_increment primary key, you can select a random number between the lowest and highest primary key. You might assume `1` is the lowest and you get the highest with `MAX()`.

Then do a query like this, where the random value is `58494`:

```
SELECT * FROM shopaholic WHERE ID >= 58494 LIMIT 1
```

If you don't have any gaps in the primary key, you could use `=` instead of `>=`.

This query will be fast since it is reading just one record. So, do this in a loop (e.g. 36 times for a list of 36 records). If you are keeping track of which records they've seen, then check each record against that dataset to see if they've seen that record already. You could also check to see if this is already loaded for the page so you don't get duplicates on the same page at least.

If you're trying to find records that the user hasn't seen already, as the user pages through the results, it will become increasingly expensive to find a record "randomly" which they haven't seen yet, especially as the dataset grows. Yet another reason not to worry about repeats.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. If it makes a difference, I'm not worried at all about a user seeing the same result if they refresh the page. Within one viewing, though, I want to give the feeling of scrolling through all the rows relevant to them, albeit in a shuffled order.

Comment: @Sebastian, how many total records are there likely to be? How many records is a user likely to scroll through?

Comment: A user follows multiple feeds and each feed contains all the sale items on a particular website, so it could easily be hundreds of records for each user.

Comment: @Sebastian, does it really have to be random? Why not sorted by price, relevance, date, etc? Anyway, "hundreds" isn't much. If it has to be random, and no repeats, and since it seems likely with such a low number that they may actually scroll through them all, just randomly order the list using `ORDER BY RAND()` and store it (client or server side), then page through them.

Comment: The reason I want it to be random is because this is a Chrome extension that puts this feed on the user's new tab page so I'm looking to deliver fresh content every time they open a new tab. Even if it were thousands, would `ORDER BY RAND()` still be feasible?

Comment: @Sebastian, if storing a list of thousands per user seems feasible.